# It's there a way to archived Jira Issue and worklog

Tags: jira

i try to find a way to archive project, issue and worklogs from jira to another database to increase performance.

It's someone already write a tools or have some sample of code to use to execute this goal ?

I think pass by the api will be to much expensive in ressource, so maybe i would like to pass by the database

It's there a way to transfert all old "items" who was not modified past a year ?

thanks

Comment: Have u considered the xml backup option on JIRA.

Comment: XML backup options, and after that i delete old projets, issue from the live instance ?

Comment: AFAIK, XML backup and optional restore of individual Projects is the best practice. Then you can delete old Projects from production.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool I made for my needs which basically allows to convert Jira project to html website - maybe it will be useful for you: https://gitlab.com/kaszaq/jiratomkdocs/